# Separate one process into several processes in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, process

I have a function SetCameraChannel which will open the camera channel based on the device data in database. I tested to open 5 channels and it works fine (around 400,000K memory though), but if I open 20 channels, it will lead to "Failed to allocate memory".

Is it possible to separate the 20 channels into 4 different processes (1 process contains 5 channels) and when a channel cannot be opened, it will automatically trying to re-open the channel?

Or do you have any idea how to run 20 channels without having memory allocation problem?

```
private void SetCameraChannel()
{
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
    {
         foreach (DataRow dr in dtFDInfo.Rows)
         {
             FDCamera fdCameraChannel = null;
             url = string.Format("rtsp://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/live/video/h264/record/ch{4}?tcp", dr["SourceUserId"], dr["SourceUserPw"], dr["SourceIp"], GetChannelPort(dr), GetDeviceChNum(dr));
             if (fdCameraChannel != null)
             {
                 fdCameraChannel.Dispose();
             }

             fdCameraChannel = new FDCamera(dr["device_name"].ToString(), url, dr);
         }
     }));
}
```

Comment: Process separation doesn't help you to get much memory. Is your process x86? Do you check your memory amount of your process manager in somewhere like Task Manager?

Comment: How separating processes will reduce memory usage?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh yes, I do check the memory in Task Manager. If I run  5 channels then it will be aroud 400,000K-500,000K but if I run 20 channels it will over than 1,600,000K

Comment: @Reniuz if I could separate it into 4 processes, there will be 4 processes with each process around 400,000K-500,000K memory. But if I don't separate the process, it means I cannot run 20 channels at all.

Comment: It all depends on _why_ you failed to allocate memory. If your disk is full, splitting the work into processes won't help. If you're running your process as 32-bit and simply hitting the process's virtual address space limit, then it would. But then in that case the best solution would not be to add complexity in the form of extra processes, but rather to just run the program as 64-bit.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I cannot run it as 64-bit because client's computer is 32-bit

Comment: If you running 1 process and able to start 5 channels it consumes 500mb and fails if you start 20 channels. So application unable to allocate 2Gb of memory. 1 process 20 channels = 2Gb and 4 processes 5 channels each = 2Gb - you still unable to run 20 channels.

Comment: @currarpickt: it would be cheaper for your client to just upgrade the computer, than to pay you to work around his memory limitations. Or if it wouldn't be, maybe you should ask for a raise? :)

Comment: @Reniuz is it max 2Gb for 1 process or max 2Gb for all process? CMIIW, I think the max 2Gb is for 1 process, so if I run several processes as long as each of them is less than 2Gb, then it's okay.

Comment: @PeterDuniho is it not possible to run it into several process such as in Chrome?

Comment: can you start 4 programs with 5 channels each?

Comment: @reniuz yes, I even try to run 5 programs with 5 channels each and it works

Comment: @currarpickt: it's possible, but it's non-trivial, to say the least. You can spend many many hours working on the problem to get your program to work in that distributed model correctly. For a few hundred dollars, your client could buy a brand new computer that can run 64-bit software. Even if _all_ they used the computer for was this one program, they would get the solution faster, it would work more reliably, and would be far cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can create named process dynamically from C# using AssemblyBuilder and TypeBuilder classes and create your channels as required inside each processes, so memory allocation will be split across different process and can be managed properly.